# These sentences sound awkward, how can I fix them?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

> *Blabbermouth blabbed for 5 min explaining what had happened in Kahani. The shadows had started rebelling. They were trying to disconnect from their people. It was causing massive havoc.*

These sentences sound really awkward for some reason when I read them. Is there anything I can do to make them more interesting?

Comment: please take a moment to read the [help].

Comment: Please note that this site is neither a proofreading service nor a writing workshop; we may be able to help you, but you must identify *specifically* what you find awkward and why, and what research you have already attempted.

Comment: Is this an original composition or a translation?

Answer (score 2):

The paragraph is too choppy; the individual sentences do not flow as a coherent whole.

Try something like this:

*Blabbermouth blabbed for five minutes explaining what had happened in Kahani:  the shadows had started rebelling!  They were trying to disconnect from their people, causing mass havoc.*

("*Massive*" means "containing a large amount of matter"; "*mass*" refers to an undifferentiated, homogeneous group. In this case, the group is "*their people*".)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound awkward, but rather strange, probably out of lack of context. I would change the following words however:

> Blabbermouth blabbed for 5 min explaining what had **gone down** in Kahani. The shadows had started rebelling. They were trying to disconnect from their people. It was **creating chaos**.

Comment: 'Gone down' (= 'happened') is an Americanism, and would probably be understood in other English-speaking countries only to a limited extent.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that the sentences are a little incoherent because:

1. The (repeated) use of 'had'.

*Blabbermouth blabbed for 5 min explaining what **had** happened in Kahani. The shadows **had** started rebelling. They were trying to disconnect from their people. It was causing mass havoc.*

2. The vague 'It' (what is it?).

And as Aaron Endelman suggests, it is choppy.

Perhaps try:

*Blabbermouth blabbed for 5 min explaining what **occurred** in Kahani, **and now** the shadows **were** rebelling. They were trying to disconnect from their people, causing mass havoc.*